# Elasticsearch multi-match cross fields query with different query analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

**USE CASE:**
I have a collection of `companies`. Each company has information of `city` and `country`. I want to be able to make text searches to find for example companies in Bangkok - Thailand. All the information must be searchable in different languages.
Example:
In Brazil most people refer to Bangkok in english version, and not `Banguecoque` as the brazilian one. In this case if a person wants to search for companies in Bangkok - Thailand, the search sentence will be `bangkok tailandia`.
Because of this requirement I must be able to search across different language fields to retrieve the results.

**PROBLEM:**
When sending queries without specifying the analyzer Elasticsearch use the search_analyzer specified on each field configuration. The problem is that it breaks the purpose of cross fields query.
This is the analyzers configuration:

```
"query_analyzer_en": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "stopwords_en" ]
},
"query_analyzer_pt": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": [ "lowercase", "asciifolding", "stopwords_pt" ]
}
```

Each analyzer usess a different `stop` filter by language.

This is the fields configuration:

```
"dynamic_templates": [{
    "english": {
        "match": "*_txt_en",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer_en",
            "search_analyzer": "query_analyzer_en"
        }
    }
}, {
    "portuguese": {
        "match": "*_txt_pt",
        "match_mapping_type": "string",
        "mapping": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "index_analyzer_pt",
            "search_analyzer": "query_analyzer_pt"
        }
    }
}]
```

This is the query I'm using:

```
{
   "query": {
      "multi_match" : {
        "query" : "bangkok tailandia",
        "type"  : "cross_fields",
        "operator":   "and",
        "fields" : [ "city_txt_en", "country_txt_pt" ],
        "tie_breaker": 0.0
      }
   },
   "profile": true
}
```

After profiling the query the result is:

```
(+city_txt_en:bangkok +city_txt_en:tailandia) 
(+country_txt_pt:bangkok +country_txt_pt:tailandia)
```

It's not working properly because Elasticsearch is trying to match both terms in `city` and `country` fields. The problem is that the term **bangkok** is in english and the term **tailandia** is in portuguese.

If I set a analyzer on the query the lucene query is the way I expect:

```
+(city_txt_en:bangkok | country_txt_pt:bangkok) 
+(city_txt_en:tailandia | country_txt_pt:tailandia)
```

But now the problem is that I must use the same query analyzer to both languages. I need a way to generate the lucene query above using different query analyzers by language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to implement this using `[query_string][1]`. 
Query string breaks the terms and then applies them across each field as per the analyzer. 
Example:

```
{
   "query": {
      "query_string" : {
        "query" : "bangkok tailandia",
        "default_operator":   "AND",
        "fields" : [ "city_txt_en", "country_txt_pt" ]

      }
   },
   "profile": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, [`cross_fields` mandates that all fields have the same analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#_literal_cross_field_literal_and_analysis)

What you could do, however, is to split your query in two parts like this where each part has an equal chance of matching. Here you could use a `match` since each `multi_match` has a single field, but you can also add other fields having the same analyzer in each sub-query

```
{
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
              "multi_match" : {
                "query" : "bangkok tailandia",
                "type":       "cross_fields",
                "operator":   "and",
                "fields" : [ "city_txt_en" ],
                "minimum_should_match": "50%" 
              }
            },
            {
              "multi_match" : {
                "query" : "bangkok tailandia",
                "type":       "cross_fields",
                "operator":   "and",
                "fields" : [ "country_txt_pt" ]
              }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use a `"minimum_should_match": "50%"` it means that for each query it must match at least one of the two terms. The problem is that if the two queries matches `bangkok` but not `tailandia` the documents will be retrieved. But I need to retrieve just documents that matches `bangkok` AND `tailandia`.

Comment: If I break the query in two queries (one query for each term) using `bool/must` it works. But I don't want to create this logic on my API. I just want to send the sentence to Elasticsearch, There is any option to do this without breaking queries by term?

Comment: Maybe can you explain what your use case is, i.e. why your users are searching in two different languages within the same query? That might interest other people as well.

Comment: Are there stopwords in portuguese that are not stopwords in english and vice versa?

Comment: Maybe lots of stop words in english doesn't exists in portuguese and vice versa. But stopwords are just an example. We can have synonyms and stemming per language for example. Other point is that I want to index lots of languages. So in this case I can have a bigger chance to create problems if not breaking the information in different fields.